# How do I use Multiple Substitutions in Lookups for Log4J 2 configurations? Is it possible?

Tags: java, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I have a situation in which I want **Log4J 2** to determine which directory to use for logging. The pseudocode is as follows:

```
property LOG_DIR = "./logs" // default
if (isDIR(${env:LOG_DIR}) {
  LOG_DIR = "${env:LOG_DIR}"
} else if (isDir(${sys:catalina.base}) {
  LOG_DIR = "${sys:catalina.base}/logs"
}
```

The configuration I have for properties (in `log4j2.xml`) is as follows:

```xml
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_DIR">${sys:catalina.base}/logs:-logs</Property>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %t/%c:%L | %m%n</Property>
    <Property name="JAVA_HEADER">${java:version} - ${java:os}</Property>
  </Properties>
  <!-- Other configuration here -->
</configuration>
```

What I think it should look like:

```xml
<!-- Is this permitted? What happens if there's no Catalina Base AND no LOG_DIR env var? -->
<Property name="LOG_DIR">${env:LOG_DIR}:${sys:catalina.base}/logs:-logs</Property>
```

What I'm not sure on is how to get *both* `${env:LOG_DIR}` and `${sys:catalina.base}` options in the `LOG_DIR` property in configuration (before the default of `logs`). Is this even possible without a programmatic solution? (I'd like to avoid a programmatic solution as this config will be a template for multiple projects, some of which are libraries in SE applications. I'd like to avoid including a library that is only for configuring `Log4J`.) As far as I know, there can be only one lookup before the default. I don't know if nesting or chaining is permitted.

Comment: very nice question. Looking forward to hear from experts in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, I encountered the same problem and i stumbled upon this question. I tried at my own end and i was successfully able to solve the issue and accomplish the desired result.

```
<Property name="LOG_DIR">${env:LOG_DIR:-${sys:catalina.base:-/logs}}/somexyz.log</Property>
```

**sys:** It stands for System environment variable, this is for whole PC or your current user.

**env:** It is the run time environment variable which you configure in runner in Intellij or similar.

According to [log4J2 lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) official site: The general format of Lookup is `${sys:SOME_SYS_PATH:-default_path}` or `${env:SOME_ENV_PATH:-default_path}`.

> Now as per your requirement, You want to see if a file path is
>   configured in runtime environment or not, if yes then save all logs 
>   event data at that place. If no file is configured in runtime
>   environment then look for system environment, if path is configured
>   there then save all logging information there else save all logging
>   information to a default path i.e `/logs`.

**Use below code and it will work for you.**

```
<Property name="LOG_DIR">${env:LOG_DIR:-${sys:catalina.base:-/logs}}/somexyz.log</Property>
```

**If file path is configured in runtime environment then save it there, else check if path is configured in system environment(PC) and save there , else save it in default path */logs*.**

Comment: Thank you; I will try this when next I work on a Java EE app.

Comment: Is there any way I can use `sys:catalina.base/logs` instead of `sys:catalina.base` in the substitution? I've tried it in the first form and my log file isn't being created in any of the locations specified: `<Property name="LOG_DIR">${sys:catalina.base/logs:-${env:LOG_DIR:-/logs}}</Property>` ... `<RollingFile name="MonthlyFile" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/${APP_NAME}.log"`. (`$LOG_DIR` resolves to `/var/logs`). I want to avoid duplicating the `logs` directory (`fileName="${LOG_DIR}/logs/${APP_NAME}.log"`) or placing the log file directly in `sys:catalina.base`.

Comment: I still can't figure out how to substitute in `${sys:catalina.base}/logs` as the first place to look before trying `${env:LOG_DIR:-/logs}`. Should I not specify this as a `<Property name="CATALINA_LOG">${sys:catalina.base}/logs</Property>` and then do something like `<Property name="LOG_DIR">${CATALINA_LOGS:-${env:LOG_DIR:-/logs}}</Property>` or should I leave it out of the property and use `<RollingFile fileName="${CATALINA_LOGS:-S{LOG_DIR}}/${APP_NAME}.log" ... >`?

Comment: After doing some research/experimentation, I've found that `${CATALINA_LOGS:-S{LOG_DIR}}` doesn't work (IOException is thrown) for a `RollingFile` because `${CATALINA_LOG}` doesn't exist for a desktop app when the library containing this config is used in one. It also doesn't work when used for substitution in a `<Property ...>` declaration as logs end up in `${env:LOG_DIR:-/logs}` for web apps (which is fine, but not what I was expecting).

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer did point out correctly that a lookup expression can be used as the default value inside another lookup expression. My requirement was to allow the configuration to reside outside of WEB-INF and allow two different locations for that. Luckily, this also works for the web.xml configuration:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///${sys:myapp.home:-${sys:user.home}}/myapp/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If system property myapp.home is not set, user.home will be used instead. This overrules the default location (WEB-INF/log4j2.xml). If the indicated file doesn't exists, only the search on the classpath is left. So I put a fallback configuration into WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Thank you, @eddelplus. That looks like a far more sensible solution. I will try that if I ever do Java development again.